# Importing link breed in netlogo using nw:load-graphml

Tags: netlogo, graphml

How can I get NetLogo to recognize link breeds when importing a graphml file?

I have specified breed attributes in the graphml file and named the breeds in NetLogo. When imported into NetLogo using `nw:load-graphml`, I believe NetLogo should assign `breed` to `links` by reading the `breed` attribute in the graphml file. As described in [NetLogo documentation](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/nw.html#nw:load-graphml):

> ...`nw:load-graphml` will try to assign the attribute values defined in the GraphML file to NetLogo agent variables of the same names (this is not case sensitive). The first one it tries to set is `breed` if it is there, so the turtle or link will get the right breed and, hence, the right breed variables.

However, despite specifying link breeds in NetLogo and the graphml file, links are assigned the generic "links" breed upon import.

Example graphml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns
         http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
  <key id="v_name" for="node" attr.name="name" attr.type="string"/>
  <key id="e_breed" for="edge" attr.name="breed" attr.type="string"/>
  <graph id="G" edgedefault="undirected">
    <node id="n0">
      <data key="v_name">1</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n1">
      <data key="v_name">2</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n2">
      <data key="v_name">3</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n3">
      <data key="v_name">4</data>
    </node>
    <node id="n4">
      <data key="v_name">5</data>
    </node>
    <edge source="n1" target="n2">
      <data key="e_breed">ftf-tie</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="n0" target="n3">
      <data key="e_breed">ftf-tie</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="n0" target="n4">
      <data key="e_breed">ftf-tie</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="n1" target="n4">
      <data key="e_breed">ftf-tie</data>
    </edge>
    <edge source="n1" target="n4">
      <data key="e_breed">sns-tie</data>
    </edge>
  </graph>
</graphml>
```

NetLogo import code:

```
extensions [ nw ]

undirected-link-breed [ ftf-ties ftf-tie ]
undirected-link-breed [ sns-ties sns-tie ]

to setup
  clear-all
  nw:load-graphml "test.graphml"
  repeat 30 [ layout-spring turtles links 0.2 5 1 ]
end
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do your link breeds have the same number of variables? You can change the breed with a statement `set breed <new-breed>` but that's not going to help if the breeds have different variable sets. It may be you need to do something ugly like read in the graphml to the generic links breed and have variables like 'var1', 'var2'. After reading, you can then change both the breed and the attribute variables.

Comment: @JenB Thankfully, all link breeds do have the same variables! I have been unable to read in unbreeded links and then `set breed <link-breed>`, because NetLogo doesn't allow breeded and unbreeded links in the same world. Am I missing something?

Comment: Update: Changing from singular-breed to plural-breed in the file (e.g., from `ftf-tie` to `ftf-ties`) resolved this issue. See: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/189

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing from singular-breed to plural-breed in the graphml file (e.g., from `ftf-tie` to `ftf-ties`) resolves this issue completely.

See: https://github.com/NetLogo/NW-Extension/issues/189